# LogoutView() received an invalid keyword 'name'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class?

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to name my url and I get the following error:

error:

```
LogoutView() received an invalid keyword 'name'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.
```

url:

```
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html', name='logout')),
```

working on a project and stuck atm. TIA

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `name` argument is for `url()` not `as_view()`. Move it outside of `as_view`.

Answer (score 1):

your error is a typographical "name" that must go outside the parentheses. Just like that:

```
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```